# Who wrote "What are TeX, LaTeX, and friends?"

Tags: books

Who wrote [What are TeX, LaTeX, and friends](http://www.ctan.org/what_is_tex.html)? I want to reference it in my article.

Comment: Definitely Jim Hefferon -- the page contains a link to his math textbook (see item #6).

Comment: Jim Hefferon's name is in the top page logo. Or was that introduced only very recently?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Me.

This "system" won't let me post in less than 30 characters so here is some extra baloney at the end to fill out the required empty space.  Ridiculous.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can outsmart the setting you're so annoyed with by first creating an answer that contains more than 15 characters, and then reopening the piece and deleting all but the first three characters.

Comment: I think you should try Mico's suggestion: having just the answer "Me" would be incredible.

Comment: @percusse "I" will get changed by the English language police.

Comment: +1 for being the first correct SE answer I see that only involves saying "me"

Comment: The 'back end' has been altered so that editing to under 30 characters is no longer allowed, even if you try the `<!-- ... -->` approach. While it is in this case not ideal, there is a reason for the 'no very short answers' rule!

Comment: @AndrewStacey "Me" seems to be a very valid answer in some of the pidgin English dialects I encounter everyday and no I'm not an anthropologist or linguist! "Give me back me pen", "He didn't do it, nor me" ;)

Comment: @AndrewStacey I wood of often specially herd you're last one to...entering the realms of silliness now, where would one stop!

Comment: This has to be the answer with better rep-to-char-count ratio across all Stack Exchange sites :)

Comment: @AndrewStacey, @_Leeser, @_SteveD (and others): Don't worry all, @_JimHefferon likes his stuff untouched...